# Why are my variable values being deleted?

Tags: c, substring

I am trying to extract substrings in C. I have an input to my function of a string (char command[]) and am taking out parts of it. Upon debugging my code, I notice that values (condition and accumulate) are being erased when I reach later parts of the function. Why is this? (See code below)

```
int multiply(char command[]) {
    char condition[5];
    memmove(condition, command, 4);
    condition[3] = '\0';
    char accumulate[2];
    memmove(accumulate, &command[4], 1);
    accumulate[2] = '\0';
    char set[2];
    memmove(set, &command[5], 1);
    set[2] = '\0';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

According to the debugger, condition is erased when set is defined and accumulate is being erased upon EXIT_SUCCESS.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? As in, where should the substring you calculate end up? I've answered explaining what is happening, but I can't help you get the function working properly without more details @Ben Dent

Comment: `accumulate[2] = '\0';` is *undefined behaviour* because it is indexing the array `char accumulate[2];` beyond its bounds.

Comment: And the same with `char set[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`condition` is erased when `set` is defined because you don't use `condition` after you've defined `set`, so your compiler optimizes by storing the two in the same location.

`accumulate` is erased when you return from the function because it is a local variable.

Comment: I think the reason has more to do with [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330547/why-are-my-variable-values-being-deleted#comment99268252_56330547) than compiler optimisation or local variables.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm gonna have to disagree with you here. Even after fixing the out of bounds writes, I still see the same behaviour. It's a very common optimisation to use the same chunk of memory for two variables that are used at different times as seen here.

Comment: In that case optimisations should be turned off when debugging. It wasn't clear to me what "erased" means when there is UB messing things up.